# Huggingface - Finetuning in Tensorflow with custom datasets

Tags: tensorflow, huggingface-transformers, transfer-learning, huggingface-tokenizers, fine-tuning

I have been battling with my own implementation on my dataset with a different transformer model than the tutorial, and I have been getting this error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'dtype'`, when i was starting to train my model. I have been trying to debug for hours, and then I have tried the tutorial from hugging face as it can be found here https://huggingface.co/transformers/v3.2.0/custom_datasets.html. Running this exact code, so I could identify my mistake, also leads to the same error.

```
!wget http://ai.stanford.edu/~amaas/data/sentiment/aclImdb_v1.tar.gz
!tar -xf aclImdb_v1.tar.gz

from pathlib import Path
def read_imdb_split(split_dir):
    split_dir = Path(split_dir)
    texts = []
    labels = []
    for label_dir in ["pos", "neg"]:
        for text_file in (split_dir/label_dir).iterdir():
            texts.append(text_file.read_text())
            labels.append(0 if label_dir is "neg" else 1)

    return texts, labels

train_texts, train_labels = read_imdb_split('aclImdb/train')
test_texts, test_labels = read_imdb_split('aclImdb/test')

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
train_texts, val_texts, train_labels, val_labels = train_test_split(train_texts, train_labels, test_size=.2)

from transformers import DistilBertTokenizerFast
tokenizer = DistilBertTokenizerFast.from_pretrained('distilbert-base-uncased')

train_encodings = tokenizer(train_texts, truncation=True, padding=True)
val_encodings = tokenizer(val_texts, truncation=True, padding=True)
test_encodings = tokenizer(test_texts, truncation=True, padding=True)

import tensorflow as tf

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((
    dict(train_encodings),
    train_labels
))
val_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((
    dict(val_encodings),
    val_labels
))
test_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((
    dict(test_encodings),
    test_labels
))

from transformers import TFDistilBertForSequenceClassification

model = TFDistilBertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('distilbert-base-uncased')

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=5e-5)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=model.compute_loss) # can also use any keras loss fn
model.fit(train_dataset.shuffle(1000).batch(16), epochs=3, batch_size=16)
```

My goal will be to perform multi-label text classification on my own custom dataset, which unfortunately I cannot share for privacy reasons. If anyone could point out what is wrong with this implementation, will be highly appreciated.

Comment: For me, the code ran successfully except that I had to add `encoding="utf8"` as a parameter to `read_text()` and at `label_dir is "neg"` you should use `==` because you are comparing values, not identities. My TensorFlow version was 2.4.1 and my Transformers version was 4.10.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be an error, when you are passing the loss parameter.

```
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=model.compute_loss) # can also use any keras loss fn
```

You don't need to pass the loss parameter, if you want to use the model's built-in loss function.

I was able to train the model with your provided source code by changing mentioned line to:

```
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer)
```

or by passing a loss function

```
loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)

model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=loss_fn)
```

transformers version: 4.20.1

Hope it helps.